# Exclude errors from Summary Report in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, report, summary

I want to exclude errors results from summary report

for example, as u see on image below, there is few errors in responses when thread was working
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0QVQ.png)

Is there any solution to exclude failed requests with errors response from summary?
Not skip with Beanshell listener, like

```
if (sampleResult.getResponseMessage().equals("Non HTTP response message: Connection reset")) {
    sampleResult.setSuccessful(true);
}
```

but exclude at all and report only success response

Answer (score 0):

1. First of all I would recommend getting familiarized with [JMeterSocketClosed](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JMeterSocketClosed) wiki article as the errors you're getting might indicate the problem with the application under test. If you're absolutely sure that the application is fine there are hints on how you can amend JMeter configuration to prevent these "Connection reset" issues from happening
2. You can mark all Samplers as successful by using [Response Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) configured like:

   [image]
3. All failed requests can be removed by [Filter Results tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/#Filter-Results-Tool) like:

   ```
   FilterResults --output-file only-success.csv --input-file original-results-file.csv --success-filter true
   ```

   Filter Reuslts Tool can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)
4. [Since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting

Comment: 1. This error relates to my app only, its not a Jmeter problem
2. mark all Samplers as successful is not a decision, I need to exclude error result from thread summary to have only successful data
3. Could I make this filter from GUI?